# Multithreading All threads started but only one thread do its job in background

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-sleep

I have an event based scenario in iis application(c#).I want to start threads and in the background when event is come  then threads do their job.My problem is in some scenario only one thread is working.When I check threads status all threads looks startted.As I understand if one thread finish work and sleep the other thread is sleep and waiting too.How can I solve this multithreading issue?I want all my threads are working in the background.When event is come then each related thread do it is job and sleep again with independent from each other.

In the application begins call ProcessMyMessages() at once.And All applicaiton lifecyle threads are working in background

.................

```
public void ProcessMyMessages() { 
    Dictionary<string,string> messages=new Dictionary<string,string>();
     messages.Add("message1","value1"); 
     messages.Add("message2","value2");
    foreach(var item in messages)
    {
    StartMessageExecuter(message,value);
    }
        }

public void StartMessageExecuter(string message,string value)
{
Thread t=new Thread(()=>ExecuteMessage(message,value));
t.IsBackground=true;
t.Start();
}

 internal void ExecuteMessage(string message,string value)
{
ThreadMessage m=new ThreadMessage();
m.ProcessMessage(message,value);
}
.....
public class ThreadMessage
{
private AutoResetEvent receiveCompleteEvent=null;

public void ProcessMessage(string message,string value)
{
using(receiveCompleteEvent=new AutoResetEvent(false))
{
DoJob(message,value);
receiveCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
}
}

public DoJob(string message,string value)
{
//Here is event base if message is comming then executed
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `receiveCompleteEvent.Set();`? When you call `WaitOne()`, it will wait forever.

Comment: I want my message1 and message2 threads lives all in applicationlifetime.In message1 thread do its job and sleep and when another event is come do the same process.If I put receiveCompleteEvent.Set() that time my thread works only once as I understand for that reason I dont want to put set() case.?Because dojob event based function when a data coming from queue then it is activated and begin to work

Comment: Where is your while loop then? The loop that will process messages.

Comment: this is sample code think ,dojob function always work ,listen and do its functions like while loop.But Am I need to put other while loop?

Comment: This is completely wrong all together, sorry. Take a look at this project: https://github.com/GregaMohorko/FileServerAndClient , especially the Main method in https://github.com/GregaMohorko/FileServerAndClient/blob/master/src/FileServerAndClient/File%20Server/FileServer.cs

Comment: Your scenario not same I think.I want my message1 threads is waiting mode until event came.

Comment: Then simply do the main loop inside of each thread.